# pageinsights не видит gzip на nginx

Tags: nginx, pagespeed-insights

Гзип включен, по крайней мере на других сайтах пишет, что все ок. гугл же посылает меня. Понять не могу в чем дело. Есть два файла конфигурационных для nginx в первом, называется default и лежит в папке sites-available:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name 188.225.33.198;

        client_max_body_size 100m;
        gzip on;
        gzip_static     on;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        gzip_min_length  20;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_vary       on;
        gzip_buffers 32 4k;
        gzip_proxied     any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;


location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/html/sergeevpasha.ru;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name sergeevpasha.ru www.sergeevpasha.ru;

        client_max_body_size 100m;
        gzip on;
        gzip_static     on;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        gzip_min_length  20;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_vary       on;
        gzip_buffers 32 4k;
        gzip_proxied     any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/html/sergeevpasha.ru/project1;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name project1.sergeevpasha.ru;

        client_max_body_size 100m;
        gzip on;
        gzip_static     on;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        gzip_min_length  20;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_vary       on;
        gzip_buffers 32 4k;
        gzip_proxied     any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

А во втором, называется nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_min_length  20;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Подскажите знающие люди, где у меня косяк =(

Comment: Как именно посылает-то?

Comment: предлагает включить сжатие, и пишет, что оно не включено - https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fproject1.sergeevpasha.ru%2F&tab=mobile

Comment: Допишите `image/svg+xml` к `gzip_types`

Comment: дописал, перезапустил Nginx - не помогает =(

Comment: Везде дописали? Вы ж раскопипастили `gzip_types` куда попало)

Comment: везде))) я не копипастил, оно само создалось и там и там =) хз как так вышло. плюс я еще дописал image/x-icon image/bmp image/png image/gif image/jpeg image/jpg и теперь в ошибке на гугле пишет как раз svg файлы, хотя для них прописано получается... я в корне запутался

Comment: для свг пришлось создать тип image/svg и соотв запись в Mime tipe хотя это уже было, но с +xml. теперь пишет следующее: Сжатие страницы https://api-maps.yandex.ru/…se&referer_host=project1.sergeevpasha.ru

Comment: в общем проблема в яндексе метрике глобальная как оказалось, не я один такой. Щас костыли изучаю как это исправить